# Characterization of the orthogonal projection in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let be $H$ a Hilbert space and $P:H\rightarrow{H}$ a linear continuous operator.
Prove thar $P$ is the orthogonal proyection onto P(H) if and only if $P^2=P$ and $(Px|y)=(x|Py)$
$\forall{x,y}\in{H}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P^2=P$, it is enough to show that $H=Ker(P)\oplus Im(P)$ and $Ker(P)$ and $Im(P)$ are orthogonal.

Let $x\in Ker(P), y\in Im(P)$, there exists $z$ such that $y=P(z)), (x|y)=(xP(z))=(P(x)|z)=(0|z)=0$.

Let $x\in H$, $x={{x+P(x)}\over 2}+{{x-P(x)}\over 2}$. Let $u={{x-+P(x)}\over 2}, v={{x-P(x)}\over 2}$.

$P(u)=0, P(v)=v$.

On the other hand, suppose that $P$ is an orthogonal projection, let $x,y\in H$, write $x=x_1+x_2, y=y_1+y_2$ where $x_1,y_1\in Ker(H), x_2,y_2\in Im(H)$. $P(x)=x_2, P(y)=y_2$.

This implies that $((P(x)|y)=(x_2|y_1+y_2)=(x_2|y_2)$

$(x|P(y))=(x_1+x_2|y_2)=(x_2|y_2)$.

Comment: But that only prove one implication, no?    Wouldn't you need to prove  that P(H) is closed as well?

Comment: But, why are you sure that you can write x as $x1_+x_2$  where $x_1,x_2$ $\in{Ker(P)}$?

Comment: Why can you write x in that way?

Comment: @mathlife $P(H)$ is automatically closed once it is an orthogonal complement of $\ker P$. The decompostion $x=x_1+x_2$ comes from the fact that $P$ is a projection. This is easy and well known fact from pure linear algebra, namely that $H=\ker P \oplus \text{Im} P$. For "orthogonal" projection you additionally need them to be orthogonal complements of each other

Comment: Butin that implication we have to prove that $P^2=P$ so we can´t assum that $H=kerP⊕ImP$

Comment: @mathlife What is your definition of orthogonal projection?

Comment: what is the definition of orthogonal projection that you use

Comment: Let be H a Hilbert space and M a closed subespace, $P_M(x)$  $(x\in{H})$ is the "part" of x which is in M

Comment: What is the definition which you are using?

Comment: @mathlife your definition is ambiguous; $H=M\oplus M^{\perp}$, so given $x=m+m'$, $m\in M$, $P_M$ is such that $P_M(x)=m$. But then clearly $P_M^2=P_M$. Of course $P_M$ defined in this way is linear and bounded.

Comment: Yes, but with your definition M should be closed and we can't prove that Im(P) is closed, without using that P is idempotent

Answer (score 0):

$Px$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $P(H)$ iff $(x-Px)\perp P(H)$ for all $x\in H$. So the condition of being an orthogonal projection onto $P(H)$ is equivalent to
$$
                            \langle x-Px,Py\rangle =0,\;\;\; x,y\in H.
$$
That is,
$$
                  \langle Px,Py\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle.
$$
Swapping $x,y$ gives
$$
                 \langle Py,Px\rangle = \langle y,Px\rangle \\
                 \langle Px,Py\rangle = \langle Px,y\rangle.
$$
Therefore $\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle Px,Py\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle$ must hold for all $x,y$ for an orthogonal projection, and this is equivalent to $P$ being an orthogonal projection. Therefore $P$ is an orthogonal projection iff $\langle Px,y\rangle =\langle x,Py\rangle$ for all $x,y$ and $P^2=P$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how you prove that $P^2=P$

Comment: $\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle x, Py\rangle$ gives $\langle Px,Py\rangle = \langle P^2 x,y\rangle$ and this must equal $\langle Px,y\rangle$ for all $y$. So $P^2=P$. Everything comes out of $\langle Px,y\rangle = \langle Px,Py\rangle = \langle x,Py\rangle$.